# Best approach to extend a Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel

We have lots of routes which do common stuff. I would like to move that stuff into a Base Route and add/overwrite functionality (e.g. adding system dependent headers, doing system dependent enrichments, etc) in the extension.

What is a good approach for that? Would it make sense to use the AdviceWithRouteBuilder since I saw only examples where it is used in unit tests?
Are there other ideas?

Thanks
Yusuf

Answer (score 2):

You can do "sub routes". I have found them very useful for doing common tasks.
Create something like this inside a "CommonRoutes" route builder:

```
// Example
from("direct:extractCommonMetadata")
  .setHeader("orderid").xpath("/data/orderid")
  .setHeader("customer").xpath("/data/customer")

from("direct:enrichWithCommonStuff")
  .enrich("foo:baz")
```

Then you can simply do this in your various routes:

```
from("foo:bar")
  .inOut("direct:extractCommonMetadata")
  .inOut("direct:enrichWithCommonStuff
  .foo("bar")

from("bar:foo")
  .inOut("direct:extractCommonMetadata")
  .to("the little house on the hill");
```

The overhead of using the direct protocol is very low and a good way to break out common functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java then its just java, and you can create a base RouteBuilder class, and do some shared stuff in the configure method, and call super.configure() from extended classes.

Comment: I know, but I like the possibility to inject something into an existing route. Is there any downside of using AdviceWith in non-tests?

Comment: Not really - Camel dont care if its for testing or not. Just mind you may want to advice before starting Camel, as otherwise advice with stops the route, advices it, and then starts it again